# How to make nested \begin{equation}\begin{aligned} environment within longtable tabular cell?

Tags: tables, equations, align, amsmath, longtable

I want to merge my three latex columns into one cell and put a tabularly arranged amsmath equation into it with nested equation / aligned like so. But I am getting the error that
"\begin{aligned} only allowed in math mode".

So at the moment I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable,varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.29\linewidth} p{0.29\linewidth} p{0.29\linewidth} |}
    \noindent\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
    &\min(\:... &&\min(\:... \\\\
    &\sum_{a \in B} x_a &&\begin{varwidth}{8em} blablabla \end{varwidth}\\\\
    &\quad+ &&\text{plus} \\\\
    &\sum_c p_c\:\cdot B &&\begin{varwidth}{8em} blablabla \end{varwidth} \\\\
    &...\:) &&...\:) 
\end{aligned}\end{equation*} &&\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Which prints this:

[image]

But I want to do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable,varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.29\linewidth} p{0.29\linewidth} p{0.29\linewidth} |}
\multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{
    \noindent\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
    &\min(\:... &&\min(\:... \\\\
    &\sum_{a \in B} x_a &&\begin{varwidth}{8em} blablabla \end{varwidth}\\\\
    &\quad+ &&\text{plus} \\\\
    &\sum_c p_c\:\cdot B &&\begin{varwidth}{8em} blablabla \end{varwidth} \\\\
    &...\:) &&...\:) 
\end{aligned}\end{equation*} 
    } \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks so much,

Comment: As always on this site please externd your example to a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Here we need to add code in order to test, and most people are too busy to do that, so they will pass on your question

Comment: So instead of actually adding a small, but compilable test document, as asked in comments, you just delete your post and ask it here again with just a code fragment?

Comment: No I think that daleif's comment was originally posted here, or at least that is where I first saw it. I just updated the testable fragments.

Comment: Ah sorry samcarter I didn't see your comment on stackexchange, I just deleted from there because I wondered whether latex stackexchange was more appropriate. Should've seen your comment there but didn't

Comment: Sorry again, I just didn't see comment because I am new to stackexchange, it won't happen again. Question has been updated now since comments

Comment: do not use the tabu package. It is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: Updated to remove tabu, wasn't core to the code

Comment: Unrelated, `a4` is not a supported class option. Use `a4paper`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed a lot of alignment issues in my document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unrelated to `longtable`. You can not have a vertical display construct like `equation*` in a `c` column which is a single line hbox.

But as far as I can tell you do not want  a vertical display here, just use the `aligned` in an inline math expression.

```
\multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{
    $\begin{aligned}
    &\min(\:... &&\min(\:... \\\\
    &\sum_{a \in B} x_a &&\begin{varwidth}{8em} blablabla \end{varwidth}\\\\
    &\quad+ &&\text{plus} \\\\
    &\sum_c p_c\:\cdot B &&\begin{varwidth}{8em} blablabla \end{varwidth} \\\\
    &...\:) &&...\:) 
\end{aligned}$}
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you very much for you answer. The reason I want the equation in a longtable is that it needs to flow seamlessly with the other tabular elements. Splitting the table might work but would get in the way and overcomplicate things.

It turns out the {c} was the problem and replacing c with p{0.96\linewidth} did the trick.

The following code runs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable,varwidth}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.29\linewidth} p{0.29\linewidth} p{0.29\linewidth} |}
\multicolumn{3}{ | p{0.97\linewidth} | }{
    \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
    &\min(\:... &&\min(\:... \\\\
    &\sum_{a \in B} x_a &&\begin{varwidth}{0.5\linewidth} blablabla \end{varwidth}\\\\
    &\quad+ &&\text{plus} \\\\
    &\sum_c p_c\:\cdot B &&\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth} blablabla \end{varwidth} \\\\
    &...\:) &&...\:) 
\end{aligned}\end{equation*} 
    } \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Thanks again

Comment: `article` does not have an option `a4`. IMHO you want `a4paper`. The `0.96\linewidth` is a little bit rough estimated. You could indeed calculate the whole width of three columns + the separation between them using `p{\dimeval{0.29\linewidth*3+4\tabcolsep}}`. And IMHO `\noindent` before `\begin{equation}` does not really make sense. But as David told, `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\begin{aligned}…\end{aligned}$}` (or maybe `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\displaystyle\begin{aligned}…\end{aligned}$}`) wouldn't need such calculations or estimations.

Comment: thanks, adjusted a4paper and removed indent, also btw that's what I did manually in the main code this was just a testing file, but I think if there's a multicolumn you only need 2\tabcolsep. Anyway I adjusted it

Comment: `\multicolumn{3}{ |\dimeval{0.29\linewidth*3+4\tabcolsep}| }` is a syntax error you intended `p` (and did not check your posted code) but why use `p` here it is better to use `$` as I showed. That would work in `longtable` or any alignment.

Comment: @cabohah `aligned` is always displaystyle

Comment: Note I did not say you could not use `longtable` I said the `longtable ` was unrelated to your issue. The `\multicolumn` in my answer could be used in `longtable`, of course, but you would see the same issue in `tabular`

Comment: Code should work now but its still rough. However I can't get the \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{$\begin{aligned}…\end{aligned}$} to work on my overleaf, nor can I get the \dimeval expression to work. But thanks again